# Is possible to reduce the complexity and spaghetti quality of this Javascript algorithm solution?

Tags: javascript, complexity-theory

Problem:
Create a function that sums two arguments together.
If only one argument is provided, then return a function that expects one argument and returns the sum.

For example, addTogether(2, 3) should return 5, and addTogether(2) should return a function.

Calling this returned function with a single argument will then return the sum:
var sumTwoAnd = addTogether(2);
sumTwoAnd(3) returns 5.

If either argument isn't a valid number, return undefined.

Solution should return:

addTogether(2, 3) should return 5.
addTogether(2)(3) should return 5.
addTogether(2, "3") should return undefined.
addTogether(2)([3]) should return undefined.

I tried everything I could, but the only thing that worked, and is purportedly the best solution so far is the following:

```
function addTogether() {
  "use strict";
  // check if argument(s) valid number
  var validateNum = function(num) {
    if(typeof num !== 'number') {
      return undefined;
    } else
      return num;
  };
  // is there is one argument or two
  if(arguments.length > 1) {
    var a = validateNum(arguments[0]);
    var b = validateNum(arguments[1]);
    if(a === undefined || b === undefined) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return a + b;
    }
  // if only one argument, return function that expects one argument and returns sum.
  } else {
    var c = arguments[0];
    // start here
    if(validateNum(c)) {
      return function(arg2) {
        if(c === undefined || validateNum(arg2) === undefined) {
          return undefined;
        } else {
          return c + arg2;
        }
      }; // belongs to return function(arg2) {}
    }
  }
}

addTogether(2)(3);
```

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @skyline3000 Next time? Probably. Note that the question already has answers now and not all answers are valid reviews on Code Review. Migrating this in it's current state would be a bad idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31306453/1541563 Something like this has been asked before. Here was my answer.

Comment: I added cyclomatic complexity analysis to my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addTogether(a, b) {
  if (typeof a == "number") {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
      return b => addTogether(a, b);
    } else if (typeof b == "number") {
      return a + b;
    } 
  }
}

// as per OP's code
// returns 3
console.log("addTogether(1, 2) = " + addTogether(1, 2));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, 3) = " + addTogether(1, 2, 3));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2) = " + addTogether(1)(2));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, 3) = " + addTogether(1)(2, 3));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, '3') = " + addTogether(1, 2, '3'));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, '3') = " + addTogether(1)(2, '3'));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, [3]) = " + addTogether(1, 2, [3]));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, [3]) = " + addTogether(1)(2, [3]));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, NaN) = " + addTogether(1, 2, NaN));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, NaN) = " + addTogether(1)(2, NaN));
// returns NaN
console.log("addTogether(1, NaN) = " + addTogether(1, NaN));
console.log("addTogether(1)(NaN) = " + addTogether(1)(NaN));
// returns undefined
console.log("addTogether() = " + addTogether());
console.log("addTogether(1)() = " + addTogether(1)());
console.log("addTogether('1') = " + addTogether('1'));
console.log("addTogether(1, '2') = " + addTogether(1, '2'));
console.log("addTogether(1)('2') = " + addTogether(1)('2'));
console.log("addTogether(1, [2]) = " + addTogether(1, [2]));
console.log("addTogether(1)([2]) = " + addTogether(1)([2]));
```

The following improvements have been suggested, but they would change the semantics of OPs code:

- return `undefined` if `a` or `b` is `NaN`, as `NaN` is not a 'valid number'
- return `undefined` if more than two arguments are provided instead of silently dropping them (thanks @PatrickRoberts)

If you don't mind returning a function for e. g. `addTogether('x')`, use:

```
function addTogether(a, b) {
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    return b => addTogether(a, b);
  } else if (typeof a == "number" && typeof b == "number") {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

This way, your will always return a `function` for one argument and `Number` or `undefined` for two or more arguments = more robust code.

For ES5 compatibility and if you don't mind `addTogether(2)()` returning a function, replace `b => addTogether(a, b)` with `addTogether.bind(undefined, a)` (thanks @PatrickRoberts).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114888/discussion-on-answer-by-le-m-is-possible-to-reduce-the-complexity-and-spaghetti).

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread operator for improving your function and some `Array` functions like `some` or `reduce` :

In that way `addTogether` can accept more than one argument. 
If `addTogether` is called with one argument, the function returned can be called with more than one arguments too.

```js
let isNotNumber = number=> typeof number != 'number';

let addTogether = function(...numbers){
  if(!numbers.length) return;
  if(numbers.length == 1){
    if(isNotNumber(numbers[0])) return;
    return function(...otherNumbers){
      if(otherNumbers.some(isNotNumber)) return;
      return otherNumbers.reduce((prev, curr)=> prev + curr, numbers[0]);
    }
  } else {
    if(numbers.some(isNotNumber)) return;
    return numbers.reduce((prev, curr)=> prev + curr);
  }
}

// Will return a value
console.log(addTogether(1,2,3));
console.log(addTogether(1)(2,3));

// Will return undefined
console.log(addTogether(1, [2]));
console.log(addTogether(1)('2'));
console.log(addTogether(1)([2]));
console.log(addTogether());
```

Comment: That won't work with "use strict", though.(also, third line -> `return unefined`<-- typo). Nice using of .some and .reduce anyway, that's a clever one!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're  right in all you say. I edited my answer and I think I fixed all the issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to [jscomplexity.org](http://jscomplexity.org/), OP's function has a cyclomatic complexity of 8 while the solution below have a cyclomatic complexity of 5 ([based on the Babel ES5 transpilation](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?presets=es2015&code='use%20strict'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20addTogether(...augends)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(augends.slice(0%2C%202).every(value%20%3D%3E%20typeof%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number'))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(augends.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%200%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%201%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(addend)%20%3D%3E%20addTogether(augends%5B0%5D%2C%20addend)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20augends%5B0%5D%20%2B%20augends%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)).

This solution is functionally equivalent to OP's code, see tests below:

```js
'use strict';

function addTogether(...augends) {
  if (augends.slice(0, 2).every(value => typeof value === 'number')) {
    switch (augends.length) {
    case 0:
      return;
    case 1:
      return (addend) => addTogether(augends[0], addend);
    default:
      return augends[0] + augends[1];
    }
  }
}

// should work (returns 3)
console.log("addTogether(1, 2) = " + addTogether(1, 2));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, 3) = " + addTogether(1, 2, 3));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2) = " + addTogether(1)(2));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, 3) = " + addTogether(1)(2, 3));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, '3') = " + addTogether(1, 2, '3'));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, '3') = " + addTogether(1)(2, '3'));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, [3]) = " + addTogether(1, 2, [3]));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, [3]) = " + addTogether(1)(2, [3]));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, NaN) = " + addTogether(1, 2, NaN));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, NaN) = " + addTogether(1)(2, NaN));
// should return NaN (not sure if this "works" or not)
console.log("addTogether(1, NaN) = " + addTogether(1, NaN));
console.log("addTogether(1)(NaN) = " + addTogether(1)(NaN));
// should not work (returns undefined)
console.log("addTogether() = " + addTogether());
console.log("addTogether(1)() = " + addTogether(1)());
console.log("addTogether('1') = " + addTogether('1'));
console.log("addTogether(1, '2') = " + addTogether(1, '2'));
console.log("addTogether(1)('2') = " + addTogether(1)('2'));
console.log("addTogether(1, [2]) = " + addTogether(1, [2]));
console.log("addTogether(1)([2]) = " + addTogether(1)([2]));
```

For reference, here is my other solution which prohibits extraneous arguments and also tests against literal `NaN` values (which ironically are `typeof "number"`). **Edit** Unfortunately due to fixing the implementation for the test case `console.log("addTogether(1)() = " + addTogether(1)());`, it now has a cyclomatic complexity of 7:

```js
'use strict';

function addTogether(...augends) {
  if (augends.every(value => typeof value === 'number' && !isNaN(value))) {
    switch (augends.length) {
    case 1:
      return (addend, ...addends) => addTogether(augends[0], addend, ...addends);
    case 2:
      return augends[0] + augends[1];
    }
  }
}

// should work (returns 3)
console.log("addTogether(1, 2) = " + addTogether(1, 2));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2) = " + addTogether(1)(2));
// should not work (returns undefined)
console.log("addTogether() = " + addTogether());
console.log("addTogether(1)() = " + addTogether(1)());
console.log("addTogether('1') = " + addTogether('1'));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, 3) = " + addTogether(1, 2, 3));
console.log("addTogether(1, '2') = " + addTogether(1, '2'));
console.log("addTogether(1)('2') = " + addTogether(1)('2'));
console.log("addTogether(1, [2]) = " + addTogether(1, [2]));
console.log("addTogether(1)([2]) = " + addTogether(1)([2]));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, 3) = " + addTogether(1)(2, 3));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, '3') = " + addTogether(1, 2, '3'));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, '3') = " + addTogether(1)(2, '3'));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, [3]) = " + addTogether(1, 2, [3]));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, [3]) = " + addTogether(1)(2, [3]));
console.log("addTogether(1, 2, NaN) = " + addTogether(1, 2, NaN));
console.log("addTogether(1)(2, NaN) = " + addTogether(1)(2, NaN));
console.log("addTogether(1, NaN) = " + addTogether(1, NaN));
console.log("addTogether(1)(NaN) = " + addTogether(1)(NaN));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't provide arguments to function. I think that this is the simplest vay:

```
function add(arg1, arg2) {

    if (isNan(arg1) || isNan(arg2)) return undefined;

    if (!arg2) {
        return functionName(arg1);
    }

    return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

Comment: isNan is not a function. change to isNaN

Comment: I see two issues: isNaN("1") == false, !0 == true

Comment: This way the user is forced to give 2 arguments, because the function wouldn't execute with 1. Not sure if it's what he wants though

Comment: the challenge states "Create a function that sums two arguments together. If only one argument is provided, then return a function that expects one argument and returns the sum." So it's an either or situation. It shouldn't force the implementation of 2 arguments from the get go.

Comment: @MariaCampbell okay, that's true, but there clearly is no `functionName`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it like this. In case only 1 argument is provided, it would return the current function, but bind the first argument, so that you only have to provide the extra argument

```js
'use strict';

function isNumeric(arg) {
  return typeof arg === 'number' && !isNaN(arg);
}

function sum(a, b) {
  if (arguments.length > 2) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (isNumeric(a) && isNumeric(b)) {
    return a + b;
  }
  if (typeof b === 'undefined' && arguments.length === 1) {
    if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
      return undefined;
    } else if (isNumeric(a)) {
      return sum.bind(this, a); // returns the sum function with the a argument bound to the current a argument
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

function test() {
  var args = '',
    result = sum,
    value;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(argument) {
    value = argument;
    if (!argument) {
      argument = 'undefined';
    }
    args += '(';
    if (Array.isArray(argument)) {
      args += Array.prototype.join.call(argument, ', ');
    } else {
      args += argument.toString();
    }
    args += '}';
    if (typeof result === 'function') {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        result = result.apply({}, value);
      } else {
        result = result.call({}, value);
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(`sum${args} = ${result}`);
}

test(2);
test([2, 3]);
test(2, 3);
test([2, undefined], 3);
test([2, "3"]);
test(2, [
  [3]
]);
test(2, "3");
test(2, [3]);
test([NaN, 2]);
```

Comment: You interpret NaN as 'not a valid number' while OP does. Still, I think your interpretation is more meaningful. We need OPs clarification. Also just out of curiosity: is the isArray() check necessary?

Comment: @le_m actually yeah, without the array or string check, they got both evaluated as a number

Comment: I don't think `sum(1, undefined)(2)` should work... better to check the length of `arguments`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You are right, I updated the code a bit and added it as a test ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about function currying, bind, call, and apply. 
Currying is applicable to ES6, but bind,call and apply run everywhere.

Details on the MDN site
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

In short, the solution you are looking for is:

```
function addTogether(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}
console.log(typeof addTogether); //-->function
console.log(typeof addTogether.bind(null,2)); //-->function
console.log(addTogether.bind(null,2)(3));//5
console.log(addTogether(2,3)); //-->5
```

Yeah, it IS that simple, not kidding!

Comment: To add, you should be willing to use the bind argument - this is a feature provided by Javascript for binding the scope and some of the arguments. (The null at the beginning binds the scope of this function.)

Comment: Note: you would of course still need to perform type checks to eliminate cases such as `addTogether(2, "3") == "23"` as per OPs request.

Comment: Noted. That's a simple **typeof a==='number' && typeof b==='number'** check. Aside, have voted +1 on the comment that suggests this should go into code review!

Comment: It took me some time to understand that this is a complexity-theory question and not a javascript question. :P Will let the response stay, might add to a discussion of how javascript simplifies complexity.

Comment: Well, the run-time complexity of all answers is identical. OP should probably clarify what kind of complexity the question refers to, probably "cyclomatic complexity".

Answer (score 0):

This is not that short, but I overcome the challenge, I'm too happy to avoid sharing my solution:

```js
function addTogether(...args) {
  if (args.length == 0) {
    //there is no args provided to the function .. lets return undefined
    return undefined;
  } else {
    //so there are arguments provided to the function
    if (args.length >= 2) {
      //there are two or more arguments provided to the function, lets consider only the first two arguments
      if (typeof(args[0]) != "number" || typeof(args[1]) != "number") {
        //so at least one of the first two arguments is not a number, lets return undefined
        return undefined;
      } else {
        //so both of the first two arguments are numbers, lets return their sum
        return args[0] + args[1];
      }
    } else { //handling input of one argument
      if (typeof(args[0]) != "number") {
        //the only argument provided is not even a number, lets return undefined
        return undefined;
      } else {
        //lets return a function that will wait for another argument 'y' to be summed with the currently provided argument 'args[0]'
        return function(y) {
          //first lets check if the second argument newly provided is a number or not
          if (typeof(y) != "number") return undefined;
          else return args[0] + y;
        };
      }
    }
  }
}


console.log(addTogether(2, 3)); // should return 5.
console.log(addTogether(2)(3)); // should return 5.
console.log(addTogether(2, "3")); // should return undefined.
console.log(addTogether(2)([3])); // should return undefined.
```