# How to remove context argument of .bind()

Tags: javascript, function, metaprogramming, bind, currying

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37838192/1541563) I became curious if it was possible to reassign `addTogether.bind` so that you could call it without the context argument. Some of the different methods I've tried are below:

```
// these are intended as separate attempts, don't execute all of them sequentially
addTogether.bind = addTogether.bind.bind(addTogether.bind);
addTogether.bind = addTogether.bind.bind(addTogether.bind(addTogether));
addTogether.bind = addTogether.bind.bind(addTogether);
addTogether.bind = addTogether.bind(addTogether);
```

My intention is to allow this:

```
function addTogether(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}

// something here to make the following possible

console.log(typeof addTogether.bind(2)); // "function"
console.log(addTogether.bind(2)(3)); // 5
console.log(addTogether(2,3)); // 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to omit the context argument to `Function.prototype.bind`. You could however do

```
function addTogether(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}
addTogether_bind = (Function.prototype.bind).bind(addTogether, null);
//                                                                ^^^^
console.log(typeof addTogether_bind(2)); // "function"
console.log(addTogether_bind(2)(3)); // 5
console.log(addTogether(2,3)); // 5
```

Comment: Oh, duh! I forgot I should have specified two arguments to `.bind.bind()`

Comment: You do realize you could switch `partial` to `bind` and this would still work. Doesn't that mean it _is_ possible? I would accept this if you remove the part that says it's not possible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: One can rename it to `bind`, yes, but it's still a different function. I'd rather not overwrite the `.bind` property for the same reasons Madara pointed out. In fact `.partial` isn't even a method any more, I just put it there for namespacing, assigning it to a completely standalone variable would've worked as well.

Comment: I understand that it's no longer a "method", all I asked was for a possible line of code that reassigns `addTogether.bind` in order to satisfy the test cases I provided. In addition, assigning to `addTogether.bind` does not overwrite `Function.prototype.bind`, it merely shadows it for the `Function` instance `addTogether`. I don't think that's dangerous, per se, but it does break convention, I'll admit.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change `Function.prototype`, something like so:

```
Function.prototype.partiallyApply = function(...args) {
   return this.bind(null, ...args);
};
```

Then you can call

```
const addTwo = addTogether.partiallyApply(2);
```

You can also directly modify `.bind()` but

1. Don't
2. You'll need to keep the old one somewhere temporarily so that you can call it
3. No, really. Don't.

Comment: Haha, good points. This was just one of those "what if" kind of questions. I would never _really_ do this in production code or anything like that. But thanks for the suggestion.