# How can I construct a infinite fun()()()...()() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Just a curious question. I want to create a function can handle infinite "layer"? make add(2)(3), add(1)(2)(3)...(10) all works.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe `return this`?

Comment: `f=_=>f` but you'll never get anything than this function as a return value...

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31306312/1541563)

Comment: @AaditMShah, sure that's related, but that's not a duplicate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm pretty sure that it's a duplicate. Both questions want a curried `add` function with a potentially infinite number of chained applications. True, one only takes a single argument at a time whereas the other one can take multiple arguments at a time. Nevertheless, the underlying idea is the same. That being said, good job on using `Symbol.isPrimitive` instead of `valueOf`. That's something I didn't know before.

Comment: @AaditMShah The linked question doesn't request infinite currying, only a single curry. Your answer there just happened to go beyond the scope of the question and somewhat answered this one. Also, it's [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive), not `Symbol.isPrimitive`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh, right. My mistake. It's been a long time since I answered that question. From the title and my vague memory I thought that it was a duplicate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, can you remove the duplicate mark? It confused others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, with a slight catch. The return value must be a function that you can coerce to a number. Here's how:

```js
function add (addend) {
  'use strict'
  const sum = (this || 0) + addend
  const chain = add.bind(sum)

  for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number.prototype)) {
    chain[prop] = Number.prototype[prop].bind(sum)
  }

  return chain
}

console.log(add(1))
console.log(add(1)(2))
console.log(add(1)(2)(3))
// convinced yet?
let four = add(4)
console.log(typeof four, four === 4)
// it's a function, not a number, so coerce to a primitive first
four = Number(four)
console.log(typeof four, four === 4)
```

`add()` is a function that contains its [context (`this`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and all the `Number.prototype` properties, including its [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) property. In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), the context behaves a lot more nicely, allowing you to define it as a primitive value like a number instead of defaulting to `window` and coercing bound primitives to `Object`s.

Comment: There should probably be note about the fact that what is returned is indeed a function, which means `add(1)(2) !== 3`, and that Number methods will not be available (e.g `toFixed`, `toExponential` etc.) even though basic arithmetics which use `toPrimitive` will work.

Comment: @WeijingLin please stop attempting to edit my answer. If you have a concern with it, use comments to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Kaiido I decided to fix that issue