# How to write a function to evaluate this expression?

Tags: javascript

Sum(6)(2,3)(6,7,8)() = 32

Sum() = 0

Sum(6,1,3)() = 10

Needs to evaluate this with single function.

Comment: I would just add up all the numbers. that's what sum means.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66305648/5459839) in the duplicate reference.

Comment: function add(...args) {
        if (args.length === 0) return 0;
        let sum = args.reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);
        return (...args) => args.length ? add(sum, ...args) : sum; 
    }