# Closure function to find the volume of a rectangle

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Hey i'm learning about closure functions and JavaScript, and decided finding the volume of a rectangle might be a good way. I also want it to not do any more math if I try to put in another number after I've already calculated the area. However, the following code only returns [Function]. It seems to just ignore me doing the math on the parameters I put in.

```js
let volume = height => {
  return function(width) {
    return function(length) {
      return height * width * length
    }
  }
}
let rec = volume(10);
rec(6)
console.log(rec(3)) //this should return 180
console.log(rec(7)) //this should still return 180
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `let rec = volume(10)(6)`?

Comment: variadic functions and currying don't go together. You can't get that behavior. You can make a curried function for your three parameters, but not get that added functionality you seek.

Comment: Why do you think the last should return 180? `10 * 6 * 7 == 420`

Comment: @ASDFGerte There are no variadic functions here.

Comment: @Barmar the desired function should "not do any more math if I try to put in another number after I've already calculated the area", as in, `volume(10)(6)(3)(7)` should stick to `180`. Maybe i misunderstood something, but i interpreted it that way.

Comment: Maybe this question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306312/javascript-function-challenge-add1-2-and-add12-both-should-return-3

Comment: You seem to be expecting `rec(6)` to modify modify `rec` somehow. It just returns a new function, which you're discarding.

Answer (score 1):

The `volume` function *returns a function*.

You assign that function to `rec`.

The `rec` function *returns a function*.

The *first* time you call `rec`, you ignore the return value completely.

The *second* and *third* times you call it, you log the result… where you will see a function, because the `rec` function returns a function.

There is no internal counter which would cause `rec` to return different things depending on how many times you call it.

Or, to rewrite your code with more verbose names:

```js
let function_that_accepts_height = height => {
  return function(width) {
    return function(length) {
      return height * width * length
    }
  }
}
let function_that_accepts_width = function_that_accepts_height(10);
let function_that_accepts_length = function_that_accepts_width(6);
let final_result = function_that_accepts_length(3);
console.log(final_result);
```

Comment: I want it to run the function and find the volume as soon as rec(3) is called without storing it in a variable

Comment: @NoahM `rec` only saves 1 dimension that came from `volume(10)`. So `rec(3)` only has 2 dimensions, you need 3 to calculate the volume.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `rec(6)` to another variable, and then call that to get all 3 dimensions multiplied.

In my code below I've renamed the variables to better express how they fit together.

```js
let volume = height => {
  return function(width) {
    return function(length) {
      return height * width * length
    }
  }
}
let line = volume(10);
let rec = line(6)
console.log(rec(3)) //this should return 180
console.log(rec(7)) //this should return 420
```

Comment: I wanna do this without assigning rec to another variable

Comment: You can chain calls: `volume(10)(6)(3) == 180`

Answer (score 0):

`volume(10)` returns a function you call `rec`. `rec` also returns a function, does it not? So you need to call that one too to get the result of `height * width * length`.

I assume `rec` comes from "rectangle"? But when you call `volume` you have only passed the `height`. You have to call the response with a `width` too to get the function that now has enough data to compute the *surface of a rectangle*.
Then you call that one with a `length` to get a volume.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm understanding